# Which is the largest U.K. LEGO shop?

Tags: lego-store, legoland

The LEGOLAND Windsor claims to have the largest U.K. Shop for LEGO, but the Leicester Square store claims to be the largest LEGO shop in the world. Which is the truth?

Comment: Welcome! There are many different measurements for "largest" (most sets, largest floor space, largest number of bricks, biggest selection of sets, most visitors, heck even most employees employed) so there can be multiple "largest UK stores" in existence. Thank marketing for that.

Comment: The LEGOLAND Windsor store is owned by the Merlin Group and not LEGO directly, where the Leicester Square store is the LEGO flagship store for the LEGO Group, so like the comment above there would need to be a bit more refinement on how you want to classify them as you could start adding in the other toy shops which sell Lego such as ToysRUs, Smiths etc

Comment: Having been to both in the last couple of weeks I would say the one in LEGOLAND seemed bigger, certainly in floor area. Leicester Square was more densely packed so selections available seemed roughly equivalent. As Adam comments I both would statements are probably true with the correct subtext. Leicester Square being the "Largest LEGO [owned and operated] Store", LEGOLAND being the largest "shop stocking only LEGO products".

Answer (score 1):

The **LEGO Store in Leicester Square** which opened in 2016 has an area of 914sq m

(Source: [Evening Standard](http://www.standard.co.uk/shopping/the-world-s-largest-lego-store-has-just-opened-in-london-s-leicester-square-a3398106.html), [Telegraph](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2016/11/17/worlds-largest-lego-store-opens-in-leicester-square/))

[image]

The **LEGOLAND Windsor Big Shop** is 'one of the UK's largest shops for LEGO' according to [their website](https://www.legoland.co.uk/explore-the-resort/land-views/the-beginning/shopping/big-shop/). In [2015](https://web.archive.org/web/20150315001021/http://www.legoland.co.uk/Explore/Shopping/) the website stated the store was '... the UK's largest one-stop shop for LEGO'. It appears as if the Leicester Square store has taken over.

[image]

The LEGOLAND Big Shop is operated by the parks owner Merlin Entertainments. As it is not an 'official' LEGO store it does accept VIP cards or have a standard pick-a-brick wall.